# Powershell - Register-PSSessionConfiguration and Connect then

Tags: powershell

I have a problem. What i want is to copy some files from network drive in session. It is not possible due to double hop. I want to try PSSessionConfiguration , but i want also to unregister it after. When i Register SessionConfiguration, and then try to connect i got error 500

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Machine -Credential -$Credentials 
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ArgumentList $Credentials -ScriptBlock { 
param($Credentials)
 Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name 4SysOps -RunAsCredential $Credentials -Force 
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Machine -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem -Path \\networkDrive } -ConfigurationName 4SysOps
```

Comment: Long shot, but try using a configuration name that starts with a letter (instead of a number)

Comment: Have you tried `-EnableNetworkAccess` to see if that helps?

Comment: When I need to copy files through a remote session, I use New-PSDrive with -Credential to map the connection (for both source and destination if needed), adjust my Copy-Item paths (or your Get-ChildItem path) accordingly, then when finished, use Remove-PSDrive. Would that not be simpler?

Comment: When I Execute Invoke to register session first, and then connect with configuration name, It works. But if i put both to script, then not

Comment: I find a solution for copy files. I add -ToSession argument to Copy-Item function, but I would like to know, what's wrong with solution from my post :(